# s3fs - Maximum file size limit

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

I need some explanation regarding s3fs, as after implementation I have some tricky issues.

1. How can we check the bucket settings after creating a bucket with default settings? What is the command, or which file should we refer for this?
2. When mounting a bucket with default settings, we face an issue with creating/uploading a file with a maximum over 20 MB. This issue is persisting, although there is enough disk space there. When we change the option: multipart_size to something over 10 (like 20,30) we get this limit increased, but the issue is that we don't know this rule of calculation. Can you give an example on this, so that we can handle that?

Comment: Please share which version of s3fs you use and the error that writing a large file emits.  It may also be useful to include the debug logs via s3fs -d -f.  Finally filing an issue via GitHub may be better than StackOverflow in this situation.

Comment: S3FS version: V1.79(commit:unknown) with GnuTLS(gcrypt)

Mounting command:

# s3fs <bucketname> <folderpath> -o url=<S3ServiceURL>

OK operation:

# dd if=/dev/zero of=upload_test10 bs=15971520 count=1

Error operation:

# dd if=/dev/zero of=upload_test10 bs=45971520 count=1
dd: closing output file 'upload_test10': Operation not permitted @AndrewGaul

Comment: Please upgrade to the latest version 1.86.  1.79 is 5 years old and has many bugs that were long ago fixed.

Answer (score 0):

s3fs uses multi-part uploads for files greater than a fixed size, 20 MB by default.  It appears that the object store you are using does not support this which you can verify in the debug logs.  You should be able to work around this via the `-o nomultipart` flag.